# Jeditable not working in IE, but works in FF, Chrome

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table made of:

```
<td class='editable' id='<?=data['id']?>' col='<?=data['col_name']?>'>Content</td>
```

`$data` is the `mysql_fetch_assoc` of the `$query`, when I click on `<td>`, the jeditable plugin activates in FF or Chrome but doesn't work in IE.

```
$(function () {
    $(".editable").click(function (event) {
        $(this).editable('ajax_save.php',{
            id          : 'id',
            name        : $(this).attr('col'),
            submit      : 'Save',
            cancel      : 'Cancel',
            tooltip     : ''
        });
    });
});
```

I couldn't figure out why this is happening, can you please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: check JavaScript console in IE

Comment: Unexpected call to method or property access on jquery.1.5.1.min.js...

Comment: almost anything is buggy on IE, I find it really hard to develop things twice, one for w3c standards and one for IE.

Comment: the error shows over here : {this.nodeType===1&&this.appendChild(a)})} ...

Comment: decided to change my code in jquery plugin, like  $(".editable").editable(... but then jquery can't get col attribute ... thus leading to mysql error... any ideas ?

Comment: did more tests and I don't think it's a problem with jeditable, I think it's a problem with either IE or Jquery when handling <td>

Comment: Answer to fix this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750973/jeditable-performance-in-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like not all options work on IE 7/8 ...

This code works

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".editable").editable("ajax.php",{
        type: "text"
    });
});
```

This doesnt

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".editable").editable("ajax.php",{
        type: "text", submit:"OK",cancel:"Cancel"
    });
});
```

Asked Mika Tuupola about this, maybe there's something wrong with the way jquery or jeditable handles td elements, wrapping the information inside a div would create overhead DOM that affects performance in case we're dealing with huge reports.